# Customizing Yocto U-boot serial prompt messages

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, bootloader, u-boot

I am using Yocto project and using U-boot for an embedded board. Trying to change U-boot prompt messages when my board is power up. For example, prompt messages is starting with U-boot "U-boot  versiyon" "U-boot.bin file creation date" and then some device driver initialization messages and so on... 
I want to customize this screen and write some self messages like "Welcome to my board" or "Device is about to open, here is the driver situations..".

I was looking source of U-boot and i found some related files like this https://github.com/u-boot/u-boot/blob/master/cmd/bootmenu.c. In this file there is a line (line 88) which is

```
printf("  Hit any key to stop autoboot: %2d ", menu->delay);
```

prints the timer when U-boot is about to be closed and linux is about be open.

I changed this line and put another string instead. Recompiled U-boot and put my U-boot.bin to my embedded board. It did not work. String did not change.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: did you try to reinstall the u-boot package?

Comment: Try running `strings U-boot.bin | grep "Hit any"` to double check your change actually made it into the new .bin file. Did you build from clean?

Comment: Yocto is installing it once from git  source. I can only modify existed one and re compile it using "bitbake" commands. The last modified attribute u-boot.bin file is changing but  I am not sure is it changing really

Comment: @RichardNixon I'll try it. I rebuild it from Yocto generated U-boot source code using "bitbake" commands for U-boot.

Comment: $ bitbake -c compile -f u-boot
 $ bitbake u-boot
These are the commands i used for recompiling U-boot on linux terminal.

Comment: maybe throw in a `bitbake u-boot -f -c cleansstate` and `bitbake u-boot -f -c clean` before your compile.

Comment: Usually the first line that U-Boot outputs to the console is its version information with the build date & time.  Did the "recompiled" version that you booted display the appropriate timestamp?

Comment: @RichardNixon using cleansstate is compeletely deleting yocto generated U-boot source code and unpacking a clear U boot source code from denx.de but that clear source code is untouchable without unpacking.

Comment: Sorry I'd assumed you had patched in your changes from your .bbappend - now I realise that you hadn't so yes a `clean/cleansstate` wouldn't be a good idea!

Comment: @RichardNixon Would patching my changes and creating another git repository for customized u-boot and modifying bbappend file for this repository be a good option ? :D

Comment: You would typically have your .bbappend's in your own meta layer in your own git repository (a whole other subject), I wouldn't personally just copy the whole u-boot source into a new repository.  Your .bbappend should only require something like `SRC_URI += "file://my-uboot.patch"`

Comment: @RichardNixon thanks for the answer. Can you tell me how can I convert my Whole U-boot folder into .patch file ?

Comment: Assuming your uboot is a git checkout then `git diff -u > my_changes.patch` should do it. If not a git checkout then make an untouched copy of the whole folder and run `diff -u -r` of the folders after you've made your changes.

Comment: @RichardNixon I don't know exactly how yocto prepared the folder but the second way seems gonna work. Thanks for all answers.

Comment: @RichardNixon I am patching U-boot using SRC_URI += like you said, then searching .bin file to check if it's including "Hit any" or not. Result is,  It's working. bin file is changing. It does not include "Hİt any" anymore. But board is still giving the same result. Even the last modified time of U-boot seems unchanged according to U-boot logs. Do you have any idea about this situation ?

Comment: Now you have everything built properly you could try a `clean/cleansstate` to see if that helps

Comment: @RichardNixon Thank you, but the result is still same. It's really getting interesting. Binary files are including the strings I want to put on the screen. Their last modified date are also changed but result is not changed. I also deleted all tmp and sstate files and rebuild whole things using bitbake fsl-image-full but result is same again :D

Comment: You posted your question almost 5 days ago.  If you download a tarball of the U-Boot version you want, untar it in a directory,  edit/patch your changes, setup **PATH** to your toolchain, run `make xxx_defconfig` and `make`, then in less than two hours you would probably have a **u-boot.bin** in that directory.

Comment: Problem solved using @RichardNixon 's diff -u -r method.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend **not** following the path you are on. Yocto is a fine for distributions, but if you are running custom bootloaders and kernels it is not a clean way to go. I know it's pitched as that, but patching is a not great way to do this. It's painful, slow, and error prone. Maybe if all you are doing is changing the command prompt...

I have done a lot of embedded projects in the past and used Yocto, buildroot, LTIB... the best strategy I have found is to perform initial builds from the build system, and extract the source for the code you want to customize (bootloaders, kernels) into your own Git repo. Leverage the tool for the build dependencies of your rootfs. That is the strength of them. You will save a lot of time and energy this way and you won't need to write patches for every single change.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand you? Indeed, create patches file to customize mainstream sources is much harder than create a fork, but you just have to change bootloader/kernel/... provider by creating a custom Yocto recipe for each of those, right?

Comment: Why deal with Yocto and bitbake recipes at all? What is the value? It's abstraction from Make with no benefit, only cost. If I extract the bootloader/kernel/... source into my own git repository, I have version control/history, faster build times, and absolutely confidence in my binary. What does Yocto provide?

Comment: @linsek my product owner has yocto and u-boot support with a documentation so I am developing using these.

Comment: @Nayfe I solved the problem using diff command. I am just modifying an existed yocto recipe now.

Comment: @linsek I started to work with embedded systems nearly 3 months ago. I am learning everything step by step by reading documentations. What you say is seems to hard to me for now.